# Using, Bitmaps, and Functions

Tags: .net, memory-management, bitmap

I have a function that reads bitmaps. (There's enough code in the non-simplified function to make the separate function desirable.)

```
Function readBitmap(fName As String) As Bitmap
  Using bmp As Bitmap = New Bitmap(fName)
    Return bmp.Clone
  End Using
End Function
```

It is called like this:

```
Using qbmp As Bitmap = readBitmap(fname)
  ' play with qbmp
End Using
```

With `Using` in both the called and calling code, the bitmap is duplicated in memory for a moment, upon the function return. This can be avoided by eliminating `Using` in the function and leaving the original bitmap allocated:

```
Function readBitmap(fName As String) As Bitmap
  Dim bmp As Bitmap
  bmp = New Bitmap(fName)
  Return bmp
End Function
```

Is this a good idea? Assuming proper error handling, does it risk memory leaks or other problems? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Remember that `using` is not about memory management. It's about usage of unmanaged resources.